# How should I implement client side encryption in a jQuery file upload plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, file-upload

I am trying to implement client side encryption in the jQuery File Upload Plugin.  I have tried to follow some information I found along the lines of...

- iterate over the files array,
- replace each item with a Blob representing the encrypted file
- after the encryption is done, invoke the callback

But am struggling I currently have...

```
   var encryptFiles = function (files, callback) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = files[0];
        var blob = file.slice(0, file.size);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        reader.onload = fileonload;

        function fileonload(event) {
            var result = event.target.result;
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(result, "key");
            file.
            callback();
        }

        // iterate over the files array, 
        // replace each item with a Blob representing the encrypted file
        // after the encryption is done, invoke the callback
    }

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        add: function (e, data) {
            encryptFiles(data.files, function () {                
                data.submit();
            });
        }
    });
```

This code successfully reads the file to a blob, then encrypts it but I am unsure how to go about replacing the item with the Blob.  Can anyone give me some help.

Comment: Where do you expect data.submit() to submit to? Data does not appear to be a submittable element (such as a form)

Comment: data.submit is the MultiFile JQuery upload call. Essentially I think its a formdata object.