# Integrating CryptoJS library with jQuery-file-upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp, cryptojs

I want to integrate [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) library with [jQuery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) widget by blueimp. I want to implement cilent-side encryption for file upload and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786320/how-should-i-implement-client-side-encryption-in-a-jquery-file-upload-plugin) question was asked but not answered.

I am currently doing following procedure. But the file being uploaded is not the encrypted one that I am creating in js. Where am I making a mistake? Or is there a better way to do this?

I know that data.files[index_number] gives the file which is stored as a blob. I want to replace the file with the encrypted version of the same. So I do

```
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    var myFile = data.files[0];

    //create a blob
    var inputBlob = myFile.slice(0,myFile.size);
    reader.readAsText(inputBlob);

    reader.onload(function() {
        var strToEncrypt = reader.result();

        //get key and iv
        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("my_key");
        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("my_iv");

        //encrypt
        var encryptedObject = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt , key, { iv: iv });

        //extract and stringify ciphertext from encrypted file object
        var encryptedString = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encryptedObject.ciphertext);

        //do this procedure to convert to blob
        var byteChars = atob(encryptedString);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteChars.length; i++) {
             byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    }
        var outputBlob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "file"});

        //function to create a file from blob
        function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){
        //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add now
                    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                    theBlob.name = fileName;
                    return theBlob;
        }

        //make the final file
        var outputFile = blobToFile(outputBlob, "encr_file");

        //replace original file with this file
        data.files[0] = outputFile;
```

Please help.